# Draw signal doesn't get fired in GTKMM, when derived class doesn't call a superclass's constructor

Tags: gtkmm

**DrawingArea.hpp**

```
#ifndef __DRAWINGAREA
#define __DRAWINGAREA

#include <gtkmm.h>

class DrawingArea : public Gtk::DrawingArea
{
public:
    bool on_my_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr);

    DrawingArea(GtkDrawingArea* &cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& builder);
};
#endif // __DRAWINGAREA
```

**DrawingArea.cpp**

```
#include "DrawingArea.hpp"

#include <iostream>

DrawingArea::DrawingArea(GtkDrawingArea* &cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& builder)
{
    this->signal_draw().connect(sigc::mem_fun(this, &DrawingArea::on_my_draw));
}

bool DrawingArea::on_my_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr)
{
    std::cout << "i am here" << std::endl;
}
```

Having compiled that into the application, I have tested that the `DrawingArea` constructor does in fact get fired (I use `get_widget_derived` to connect it to Glade, but that should not be important here).

I would expect to see `"I am here"` when I start the application, or when it needs to redraw the `DrawingArea`, but it doesn't happen for whatever reason.

Despite the fact that the area is already shown, I tried to fire up `show_all_children` on the window that it's a part of, but this didn't help.

---

Now tried to add

To .hpp:

```
bool on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr) override;
```

And to .cpp:

```
bool DrawingArea::on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr)
{
    std::cout << "i am here!!!" << std::endl;
}
```

This didn't help.

Also have attempted to pass `false` as the second parameter to `connect()`, and that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was quite interesting, and rather different to what one may expect, so i'll post the answer that i got.

The issue was the i needed to initialise the object correctly. Specifically i was not calling the constructor of the superclass. I needed to do:

```
DrawingArea::DrawingArea(GtkDrawingArea* cobject, const Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder>& builder)
    : Gtk::DrawingArea(cobject) // <--- this is a very important bit
{
   //...
}
```

Without that not only the signal connection was getting lost (which is understandable, since the whole part of the object that deals with calling of the needed functions was gone), but even the overridden `on_draw` stopped working (and that's something i still do not understand).

Comment: Note that this constructor is only necessary when using Gtk::Builder to create a derived class. By the way, it should be GtkDrawingArea* cobject, not GtkDrawingArea* &cobject. See https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-builder-using-derived-widgets.html.en

Comment: @murrayc But i have said in my question that i am using Glade to create a derived class. And yes, you're correct, it's not necessary to pass the first parameter by reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler to just override the default handler - on_draw(), as in this simple example:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-cairo-drawing-lines.html.en#cairo-example-lines

These signals that return bool often have to be connected "before" in order for the extra signal handlers to be called:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-xeventsignals.html.en#signal-handler-sequence

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. But that didn't actually help at all. I tried to do both, and neither seem to be firing.