# In GTKMM, on_draw method stops being called after invalidate occurs in separated thread

Tags: c++, pthreads, glib, gtkmm

Using GTKMM, I'm extending the *DrawingArea* widget with the idea that an external process provides it with images. My *CameraDrawingArea* will then  display the images at the right size using *Cairo*.

Each time an image arrives, I store it and I call the `invalidate` method, which eventually ends up in a call to `on_draw`, where I can resize and display the image.

My problem is the following:

- The first 10 or 20 images are displayed as I expected.
- After a while, the images keep coming from the provider process, I keep calling `invalidate`
- but `on_draw` is not called any more.

To show it here, I've simplified the code so that there is nothing external to the class, and no link with other libraries. I've replaced the process providing the images by a method with for-loops, and the display of the image by printing a simple text in the middle of the widget area:

- In the constructor I launch a new `std::thread` to call the `doCapture` method in the same instance. I also set up a font description, to use it later.
- The `doCapture` method is a silly CPU eater, that does nothing except calling from time to time the `refreshDrawing` method, as long as `keepCapturing` is not `false`.
- `refreshDrawing` invalidates the whole window's rectangle via a call to `invalidate`.
- Gtk's magic is suppose to call `on_draw` and provide a *Cairo* context to draw whatever. In my case, for tests purposes, I draw a brownish centered integer.
- The class destructor stops the thread by set `keepCapturing` to false, and waits for termination with a `join`.

```cpp
    #include "camera-drawing-area.hpp"

    #include <iostream>

    CameraDrawingArea::CameraDrawingArea():
    captureThread(nullptr) {
        fontDescription.set_family("Monospace");
        fontDescription.set_weight(Pango::WEIGHT_BOLD);
        fontDescription.set_size(30 * Pango::SCALE);

        keepCapturing = true;
        captureThread = new std::thread([this] { 
                doCapture(); 
                });
    }

    void CameraDrawingArea::doCapture() {
        while (keepCapturing) {
            float f = 0.0;
            for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {
                for (int m = 0; m < 1000; m++) {
                    for (int o = 0; o < 500; o++) {
                        f += 1.2;
                    }
                }
            }
            std::cout << "doCapture - " << f << std::endl; 
            refreshDrawing();
        }
    }

    void CameraDrawingArea::refreshDrawing() {
        auto win = get_window();
        if (win) {
            win->invalidate(false);
            std::cout << "refreshDrawing" << std::endl; 
        }
    }

    bool CameraDrawingArea::on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr) {
        std::cout << "on_draw" << std::endl; 

        static char buffer[50];
        static int n = 0;
        sprintf(buffer, "-%d-", n++);

        Gtk::Allocation allocation = get_allocation();
        const int width = allocation.get_width();
        const int height = allocation.get_height();


        auto layout = create_pango_layout(buffer);
        layout->set_font_description(fontDescription);

        int textWidth, textHeight;
        layout->get_pixel_size(textWidth, textHeight);
        cr->set_source_rgb(0.5, 0.2, 0.1);
        cr->move_to((width - textWidth) / 2, (height - textHeight) / 2);
        layout->show_in_cairo_context(cr);
        cr->stroke();

        return true;
    }

    CameraDrawingArea::~CameraDrawingArea() {
        keepCapturing = false;
        captureThread->join();
        free(captureThread);
    }
```

And this is my header file:

```cpp
    #ifndef CAMERA_DRAWING_AREA_HPP
    #define CAMERA_DRAWING_AREA_HPP

    #include <gtkmm.h>
    #include <thread>

    class CameraDrawingArea : public Gtk::DrawingArea {
    public:
        CameraDrawingArea();
        virtual ~CameraDrawingArea();

    protected:
        bool on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr) override;

    private:
        bool keepCapturing;
        void doCapture();
        void refreshDrawing();
        std::thread* captureThread;
        Pango::FontDescription fontDescription;
    };
    #endif
```

The problem manifests itself as follows:

- When starting the application, it faithfully displays 1, 2, 3...
- Between 5th and 20th iteration (it's random, but rarely outside these ranges), it stops refreshing.
- Because of the `cout`, I can see that `refreshDrawing` is called be sure that `invalidate` is also called, but `on_draw` isn't.

Also, if I stop the application before it stops refreshing, then it ends up nicely. But, if I stop the application after it stops refreshing, then I see this message below (the ID value varies):

```
GLib-CRITICAL **: 10:05:04.716: Source ID 25 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

I'm quite sure that I do something wrong, but clueless about what. Any help would be appreciated.

I also checked the following questions, but they don't seem to be related with my case:

- [Draw signal doesn't get fired in GTKMM, when derived class doesn't call a superclass's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554190/draw-signal-doesnt-get-fired-in-gtkmm-when-derived-class-doesnt-call-a-superc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use GTK methods from any other thread than the one in which you started the GTK main loop. Probably the `win->invalidate()` call is causing things to go wrong here.

Instead, use [`Glib::Dispatcher`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-using-glib-dispatcher.html.en) to communicate with the main thread, or use `gdk_threads_add_idle()` for a more C-style solution.

Comment: Yes, Glib::Dispatcher, that was the answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer form @ptomato, I've rewritten my example code. The golden rule is **do not call GUI functions from another thread, but if you do, then acquire some specific GDK locks first**. That's the purpose of [Glib::Dispatcher](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-using-glib-dispatcher.html.en) :

> If a Glib::Dispatcher object is constructed in the main GUI thread (which will therefore be the receiver thread), any worker thread can emit on it and have the connected slots safely execute gtkmm functions.

Based on that, I've added a new private member `Glib::Dispatcher refreshDrawingDispatcher` that will allow threads to safely the `invalidate` the windows area:

```cpp
    #ifndef CAMERA_DRAWING_AREA_HPP
    #define CAMERA_DRAWING_AREA_HPP

    #include <gtkmm.h>
    #include <thread>

    class CameraDrawingArea :
    public Gtk::DrawingArea {
    public:
        CameraDrawingArea();
        virtual ~CameraDrawingArea();

    protected:
        bool on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr) override;

    private:
        bool keepCapturing;
        void doCapture();
        void refreshDrawing();
        Glib::Dispatcher refreshDrawingDispatcher;
        std::thread* captureThread;
        Pango::FontDescription fontDescription;
    };
    #endif
```

Then, I've connected the dispatcher to the `refreshDrawing` method. I do this in the class constructor, which is called during GUI start up and therefore in the main GUI thread:

```cpp
    CameraDrawingArea::CameraDrawingArea():
    refreshDrawingDispatcher(),
    captureThread(nullptr) {
        fontDescription.set_family("Monospace");
        fontDescription.set_weight(Pango::WEIGHT_BOLD);
        fontDescription.set_size(30 * Pango::SCALE);

        keepCapturing = true;
        captureThread = new std::thread([this] {
                doCapture(); 
                });

        refreshDrawingDispatcher.connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &CameraDrawingArea::refreshDrawing));
    }
```

Finally, the thread has to call the dispatcher:

```cpp
    void CameraDrawingArea::doCapture() {
        while (keepCapturing) {
            float f = 0.0;
            for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {
                for (int m = 0; m < 1000; m++) {
                    for (int o = 0; o < 500; o++) {
                        f += 1.2;
                    }
                }
            }
            std::cout << "doCapture - " << f << std::endl; 
            refreshDrawingDispatcher.emit();
        }
    }
```

And now, this works without further problems.